# Please smb explain why the answer is 12, not 15?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def chek(x):
    if x%3==0:
        return False
    return True
a=sum([i for i in range(6) if chek(i)])
print(a)
```

Comment: Why do you think the result should be 15?

Comment: Because it is sum([1, 2, 4, 5])

Comment: From 0 to 5 how many numbers are divisible by 3? What are they? Should they be excluded from the total?

Answer (score 2):

```
[i for i in range(6) if chek(i)]
```

produces `[1, 2, 4, 5]`, omitting `0` and `3` because they have a remainder of 0 when divided by 3, and therefore are not included in the listcomp output. The sum of 1, 2, 4 and 5 is 12.